How to extend the slice map $S_f: A\otimes B \to A$ given $f \in B^*$ to the multiplier algebras?
I have two questions regarding the slice map $S_f: A\otimes B \to A$ for $f \in B^*$ defined by $S_f(\sum a_i\otimes b_i)= \sum a_i f(b_i)$.
(1) What is the canonical way of extending this map to the multiplier algebras $M(A\otimes B) \to M(A)$? It seems that the second factor imbedding is used, but I want to know the precise reference about it.
(2) Given a locally compact Hausdorff group $G$, we can define a map $W_G: G \to M(C^*(G))$ by $W_G(s)=\delta_s$ where $\delta_s$ is a point-mass as a measure. Then why is true that $S_f(W_G)=f$ for $f\in A(G)$ where $A(G)$ is the Fourier algebra of $G$? Here we should be able to view $W_G$ as an element of $M(C_0(G)\otimes C^*(G))$, but this is also unclear to me.
Thank you for your help!




I'm assuming that $A,B$ are $C^*$-algebras and $\otimes$ is the minimal $C^*$-tensor product. Since any $f\in B^*$ is a linear combination of four states, it is enough to assume that $f$ is a state. Long story short, slice map $S_f=id\otimes f$ extends to multipliers, because it is strict and CP. More precisely, this claim is a special case of Proposition 8.2 and Corollary 5.7 in "Hilbert C*-modules. A toolkit for operator algebraists"- Lance. See also discussion after Proposition 8.2, where slice maps are mentioned explicitly.
As a side remark, even before extending to multiplier algebras, existence of slice map $A\otimes B\rightarrow A$ isn't that obvious, since $\otimes$ is not the algebraic tensor product (slice map is characterised by $S_f(\sum_i a_i\otimes b_i)=\sum_i a_i f(b_i)$, but not defined by it) - existence is also proved in given references.
2)
There is a lot going on here, let me go slowly. I will denote by $C^*(G)$ the full $C^*$-algebra of $G$ with "generators" $u_g\in M(C^*(G))$, by $C^*_r(G)$ the reduced $C^*$-algebra with "generators" $\lambda_g\in M(C^*_r(G))$ and by $vN(G)$ the group von Neumann algebra of $G$, i.e. $vN(G)=C^*_r(G)''\subseteq B(L^2(G))$. There is a canonical map $\Lambda\colon C^*(G)\rightarrow C^*_r(G)$, which is a non-degenerate surjective $*$-homomorphism, after extending to multipliers it acts via $u_g\mapsto \lambda_g$. I will also change the notation of slice maps to $S_f=id\otimes f$ as I find it easier to think about (and it's also correct).
First, one can canonically identify $M(C_0(G)\otimes C^*(G))$ with $C^{b}(G,M(C^*(G))_{str})$, the $C^*$-algebra consisting of bounded functions $G\rightarrow M(C^*(G))$ which are continuous when $M(C^*(G))$ is equipped with strict topology (and operations are pointwise). Element $f\otimes a$ corresponds to function $g\mapsto f(g)a$. This claim follows from identification $C_0(G)\otimes C^*(G)\simeq C_0(G,C^*(G))$ [Theorem 6.4.17, "$C^*$-algebras and operator theory", Murphy] and Corollary 3.4 in "Multipliers of $C^*$-algebras" - Akemann, Pedersen, Tomiyama.
With this identification, it makes sense to consider $W_G\colon G\ni g \mapsto u_g\in M(C^*(G))$ as an element of $M(C_0(G)\otimes C^*(G))$. Indeed, clearly it is a bounded function, hence it is enough to check that it is strictly continuous, which is an easy exercise (consider dense subspace in $C^*(G)$ of $\int_G h(g) u_g dg$ with $h\in C_c(G)$) - if you want me to add more details here, let me know.
Next, the Fourier algebra $A(G)$ is canonically identified with the predual $vN(G)_*$. The corresponding pairing is characterised by $\langle \lambda_g,f\rangle=f(g)$ for $g\in G,f\in A(G)$. In particular any $f\in A(G)$ gives you a bounded functional on $C^*_r(G)$ by restriction, and by composition with map $\Lambda$ you get bounded functional on $C^*(G)$, $\Lambda^*(f)\in C^*(G)^*$ (slight abuse of notation).
Putting these observations together, for $f\in A(G)$ we can consider $(id\otimes \Lambda^*(f))(W_G)$ which is an element of $M(C_0(G))=C_b(G)$. Let $g\in G$ and let $ev_g\in M(C_0(G))^*$ be the corresponding point evaluation. Then by properties of slice maps
$$ ev_g(\, (id\otimes \Lambda^*(f))(W_G))=\Lambda^*(f) (\,(ev_g\otimes id)(W_G))=\Lambda^*(f) (u_g)=\langle \lambda_g,f\rangle=f(g)=ev_g(f)$$
and as $g$ was arbitrary, we conclude $(id\otimes \Lambda^*(f))(W_G)=f$ in $C_b(G)$.

Dear Mogget, I deeply appreciate you for a kind explanation. Having no response for a while, I have thought in the following way: $\overline{S_{f}}(T)(a)=S_{f}(T(a\otimes 1_B))$ for any $a\in A$ and $T \in M(A\otimes B)$. Thus $ S_{f}(W_G)(h) =S_{f}(W_G(f\otimes \delta_{e})) = S_{f}(\sum h(s)s \otimes \delta_s) = \sum h(s)f(s)s = f(h)$ for $h\in C_0(G)$ viewing $f$ as a multiplier. How about this arguement?  Thanks!

Do you find the argument I provided unclear, or are you simply looking for an alternative one? Concerning the calculation you've written, I'm having hard time interpreting rigorously the sum $\sum$. Also, the symbol $s$ in e.g. expression $\sum h(s) s\otimes \delta_s$, do you mean here the delta-function $\delta_s$?
